# scons can't find glib-2.0 >= 2.32 on cygwin

Tags: compiling, cygwin

I downloaded the source for `rmlint` and am trying to compile it on cygwin. When I run `scons`, it says `Checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.32... Error: glib-2.0 >= 2.32 not found.`

In the cygwin setup facility, it shows I have the `libglib 2.0_0 2.46.2-1` package installed. I re-installed it for good measure, but no luck.

How could I try to find the library on my filesystem, and how do I tell scons where it's located?

Comment: looks, from the error message, that it is trying to exec `glib-2.0 >= 2.32`.

Comment: @richard Yes, I am trying to figure out how to verify that it actually is installed, as the cygwin setup seems to claim, and then point scons to its location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I'm one of the rmlint dev's.

Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to get rmlint running under cygwin (although happy to be proven wrong).

Edit: have been proven wrong.  Now have [more-or-less working command-line version of rmlint](https://github.com/SeeSpotRun/rmlint/tree/cygwin) under cygwin.  It requires:

- gcc-core
- pkg-config
- libglib2.0-devel
- libtool

and optionally:

- libjson-glib 1.0-devel
- libblkid-devel
- libelf-devel

There seems to be no filemap support under cygwin so rmlint can't do its normal optimisation of file order to reduce seek times and thrash.

Comment: Hey, thanks for chiming in! : ) Would you care to comment on the technical details of why it probably won't work? I just assumed it was a problem with cygwin placing glib, not scons or your package.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being pessimistic but there are quite a few dependencies (python3-sphinx, gettext, json-glib, libblkid, elfutils, fts) and also some low-level system calls (eg stat), each of which would potentially need some debugging to get working.
Would love to have a working Windows version of course...

Comment: Well, I think it's a little early to throw in the towel. I use cygwin day-to-day, both at work and at home, transparently, with my Linux VMs. Cygwin is a full posix environment and there are quite a number of utilities and packages that run on it. I would feel pretty sure that many of them make `stat` calls.The only packages you mention that I couldn't find here https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html were `elfutils` and `fts`. There is a python-sphinx, but it's 1.2.3. So while maybe not possible atm, it's probably more possible than you imagine : )

Comment: Ok I may take a closer look.  Elfutils is only used for non-stripped binaries so is not indispensable.  Fts is used for directory traversal and looks like there is already a version in cygwin (https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/libc/fts.c;hb=3a720bf3f0d3c8f84b6b5360863544978d3ae90e) although to be honest we have never liked fts so I'm tempted to replace it with a lower-level solution eg based on opendir()/readdir().

Comment: If you install libglib2.0-devel in cygwin you will get past the pkg-config checks.  Cygwin seems to be missing a few functions (preadv, realpath, fileno) but at least it's progress

Comment: Working now: see edit above